# Comparing COUNTs with INTERSECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, intersect

I'm trying to replicate .NET's All operator in SQL but struggling with sytax. I have a query:

*Query 1*

```
SELECT ExamId FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId
```

*Query 2*

```
SELECT ExamId FROM Paper u2 JOIN UserPaper uu2 ON uu2.PaperId = u2.Id
WHERE uu2.UserId = u.id
```

I want to check whether ALL elements from Query #2 are present in query #1. This is what I have:

```
... AND
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT ExamId FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT ExamId FROM Paper u2 JOIN UserPaper uu2 ON uu2.PaperId = u2.Id
    WHERE uu2.UserId = u.id)
    I = (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId)
)
```

There's a syntax error after the equals on the last line, and I don't know how to fix it. Is there a simple fix, or is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'm missing something.  Why doesn't the second query filter on the user id?

Comment: It's part of a bigger query, I already have an aliased `User` table (`u`)

Answer (score 0):

Following on from your comment, you just don't alias the ***result*** of the sub query.

You're generating a scalar value, not a set.  Scalars don't need aliases, only sets.

But you do need to wrap `()` around the sub-query which is generating the scalar value, before you then operate on it.

```
 SELECT 1  =  SELECT 2   -- syntax error
(SELECT 1) = (SELECT 2)  -- good syntax, evaluates to FALSE
```

So...

```
(
  SELECT
    COUNT(*)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT ExamId FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT ExamId FROM Paper u2 JOIN UserPaper uu2 ON uu2.PaperId = u2.Id
      WHERE uu2.UserId = u.id
  )
    AS alias_for_the_intersection
)
=
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId
)
```

Comment: `I` was the alias for the intersection.

Answer (score 0):

Your groupings just got squirreled up. You need to add a `)` after the `I` alias, then drop one off the end.

As it sits, it's comparing the `FROM` clause in part one to the second query instead of comparing the two counts.

Currently:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT ExamId FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT ExamId FROM Paper u2 JOIN UserPaper uu2 ON uu2.PaperId = u2.Id
    WHERE uu2.UserId = u.id)
    I = (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId)
)
```

Should be:

```
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT ExamId FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId 
    INTERSECT
    SELECT ExamId FROM Paper u2 JOIN UserPaper uu2 ON uu2.PaperId = u2.Id
    WHERE uu2.UserId = u.id)
    I) = (SELECT COUNT(*) c FROM UserExam where UserId = @UserId)
```